# echo "<script>windows.open('view_users.php','_self')</script>"; - is not working

Tags: php

I'm faily new at this so please help.

I'm doing and admin panel, and once I put my email and password, it doesn't go to the page I created (view_users.php). I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BFVyxoJcNzA&list=PL3oMl9a6mutmCqVoHrhFd5LpQUbZR128v&index=8) tutorial. Everything works until minute 15.47. 
This is a school project, nothing too fancy.
Here is the php part of the code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
mysql_connect('','','','');
mysql_select_db("");

if(isset($_POST['admin_login'])){

$admin_name = $_POST['admin_name'];
$admin_pass = $_POST['admin_pass'];

$query = "select * FROM admin WHERE admin_name='$admin_name' AND admin_pass='$admin_pass'";

$run = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0){
echo "<script>windows.open('view_users.php','_self')</script>";

}

else {
    echo "<script>alert('Admin details are incorrect!')</script>";
}
}

?>
```

oh and yes, I did creat the table with the admin email and pass.

please help.
Thank you!

Comment: it is `window.open()`. Not `windows.open()`

Comment: @YUNOWORK There is another vulnerability

Comment: @Identity1 there are probably thousands of vulnerabilities, i wasn't planning to show all of them, thats why i just posted a comment. Since this is a school project, she's probably more interested in making it work instead of making it secure.

Comment: oh! man it is a school project... Didn't read that part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change windows to window. tested and works in my localhost

```
echo "<script>window.open('view_users.php','_self')</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `windows.open` with `window.open`. `windows.open` is not an actual function.

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.open` not `windows.open`

Comment: @Uchiha Yeah Sure is but this thing has a vulnerability

Answer (score 0):

The problem is clarified that its `window.open` not `windows.open` but there are loop holes in this code. It is vulnerable to [sql ingestion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

If instead of entering a password:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='chachhundar' and password='gogo''
```

You enter password  ' or '1'='1:

```
 SELECT * FROM users WHERE admin_name='chachhundar' and admin_pass='' or '1'='1'
```